# How can we track the state of each form in expansion panel

Tags: reactjs

I'm using an array to bind the expansion panel. In ExpansionPanelDetails section there are 2 textbox which are mandatory and save button.
I'm using 'react-material-ui-form-validator' to validate the textbox but need to disable the button if textbox are empty on page load.

Can you please help how can we track the state of each form separately and disable the save button if fields are empty

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
{state.apps.map(row => (
            <StyledValidatorForm ref={this.form} instantValidate>
              <ExpansionPanel
                key={row.id}
                expanded={expanded === row.id}
                onChange={this.handleChange(row.id)}
              >
                <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                
                  <StyledUrlTypography>{row.name}</StyledUrlTypography>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                  <Typography>
                    <TextValidator
                      id="appNameField"
                      value={row.name}
                      label={<FormattedMessage {...messages.appName} />}
                      required
                      validators={['required: true']}
                      validatorListener={this.handleError}
                      errorMessages={[
                        <FormattedMessage {...messages.requiredName} />,
                      ]}
                      fullWidth
                      margin="normal"
                      onChange={evt =>
                        onAppNameFieldChange('name', row.id, evt)
                      }
                      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    />
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography>
                    <TextValidator
                      id="appURLField"
                      value={row.storeId}
                      label={<FormattedMessage {...messages.appStoreUrl} />}
                      required
                      validators={[
                        'required: true',
                        'matchRegexp:^(http[s]?:\\/\\/){1}(www\\.){0,1}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,256}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//={}]*)$',
                      ]}
                      validatorListener={this.handleError}
                      errorMessages={[
                        <FormattedMessage {...messages.requiredUrl} />,
                        <FormattedMessage {...messages.invalidUrl} />,
                      ]}
                      fullWidth
                      margin="normal"
                      onChange={evt =>
                        onAppNameFieldChange('storeId', row.id, evt)
                      }
                      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    />
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography>
                    <TextField
                      id="appDescriptionField"
                      value={row.description}
                      label={<FormattedMessage {...messages.appDescription} />}
                      fullWidth
                      margin="normal"
                      onChange={evt =>
                        onAppNameFieldChange('description', row.id, evt)
                      }
                      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    />
                  </Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                <StyledExpansionPanelActions>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={() => {
                      updateAppDetails(row);
                      this.closePanel();
                    }}
                    disabled={!formValid}
                  >
                    <FormattedMessage {...messages.updateDetails} />
                  </Button>
                </StyledExpansionPanelActions>
              </ExpansionPanel>
            </StyledValidatorForm>
          ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply disable the save button, you only need to check the two textboxes on  "emptiness". Something like `formValid = row.name != '' && row.storeId != ''` should work in this specific case.

Is there any other state of the form you would like to observe and make use of?